# json-rpc golang server curl: (52) Empty reply from server

Tags: docker, go, curl, docker-compose, json-rpc

Can anyone suggest what I'm doing wrong? I have a JSON-RPC server. If I run it using 'go run ...', everything works fine and the cURL requests go through. But when I run it using docker-compose, I get the error 'curl: (52) empty reply from server'.

I tried to use "networks_mode: host" but it didn't help

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.20 as build

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o app cmd/app/main.go

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

COPY --from=build app/app .
COPY scheme ./scheme

EXPOSE 9000

CMD ["/app"]
```

docker-compose:

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    container_name: "rpc-app_v1.0"
    ports:
      - "9001:9000"
    tty: true
    restart: on-failure
    environment:
      - RPC_ADDR=:9001
      - HTTP_ADDR=:8001
      - PG_PORT=5432
      - PG_HOST=postgres-db
    depends_on:
      - postgres-db
    networks:
      - back
    volumes:
      - .:/app

  postgres-db:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: "rpc-app-db_v1.0"
    ports:
      - "5435:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=qwerty
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_HOST=postgres-db
    networks:
      - back

networks:
  back:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors#:~:text=Images%20can't%20be%20searched,the%20continuation%2C%20readability%20%26%20extensibility.